# Controller lifecycle: when to call table.autoResizeColumn()

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently using `onAfterRendering()` hook to auto adjust the layout of a table like this:

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    var table = this.getView().byId('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < table.getColumns().length; i++) {
        table.autoResizeColumn(i);
    }
}
```

The result is not usable: all columns are sized 100% of the parent's width.

If I add a simple button to invoke the exact same logic the table gets drawn nicely. It looks like the complete table needs to be present in the DOM before `autoResizeColumn()` works properly.

My question: is there a suitable hook/event I can use to invoke the resizing once the table is in the document?

Comment: You could use onAfterRendering of the table itself.

Comment: This results in an endless loop.

Comment: The endless loop is obvious since the `autoResizeColumn` function triggers a rerendering of the Control and `onAfterRendering` is part of this rerendering again. I think that your call in onAfterRendering of the controller is a bit too early. You could try to delay it by putting your resize function in a `window.setTimeout(<yourFunction>, 0)` (or some more milliseconds). Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: That's actually my current solution. I was hoping to find a more solid one without delaying the resizing for some arbitrary time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onAfterRendering of the table as suggested and add an if statement with bResized boolean or some kind of counter to prevent the endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered you can put add a function to `oTable.onAfterRendering` but the trick is if you do any rendering in that function it will trigger another rendering event that will again trigger onAfterRendering.

The problem here is where to hang the boolean switch that determine you have done the thing you have done.

One way to get around that is to add some customer data to the table with `oTable.addCustomData`.

The pattern becomes :

```

```
oTable.onAfterRendering = function () {
// check the prototype

// read the custom data
var customData = this.getCustomData(); 

// confirm *your* custom data is in the array (and not some other custom data)

// if not do your rendering operation and then 
// set a switch to custom data
this.addCustomData(new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
    key: "myRenderingCheck",
    value: "true",
    "writeToDom": true
}));
```